# NPM is deleting old packages

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

Whenever I try to install a new package to my project, npm randomly deletes an old package that I have and then throws this error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\node_modules\axios' -> 'C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\node_modules\.axios.DE
LETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\node_modules\axios' -> 'C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\node_modules\.axios.DE
LETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\node_modules\axios' -> 'C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\node_modules\.axio
s.DELETE'] parent: 'Nasss' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\react_projects\Nasss\npm-debug.log
```

Is it facing some kind of conflict with the old packages that I have installed?

P.S: I already have the CMD running as admin.

Comment: Hi @Raymond, does npm delete a package *randomly* or does it always delete the same package? What are the dependencies between the package you install and the package(s) beeing deleted?

Is there any other process running that loaded files from your axios/ folder (e.g. node)?

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg, it randomly deletes a package. In the error above I was trying to install `react-native-device-info` and npm deleted axios instead. axios has this dependency: `"follow-redirects": "1.0.0"` and RN device info has an empty object in package.json

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344172/npm-is-deleting-old-packages/41344518#41344518) below help you? Any comments?

Comment: @rsp, Sorry for the late reply got busy. I'll check it out and inform you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with weird permissions.

It looks like npm is unable to rename the directories to other names which maybe are the old versions of the modules kept for backups if the new versions fail to get installed.

Are you sure you have the same permissions in `"Program Files\nodejs\node_modules"` **and** all of its subdirectories? It look like you may hev different permissions for existing subdirectories than you have for new subdirectories and/or the parent `node_modules`.

On Unix/Linux I would fix it with `chmod` and `chown` in one line but for Windows you will have to dive through the directories and examine the permissions.

O maybe you need to run as admin to update/install modules globally. It depends on your permissions and your configuration.

Comment: in `Program Files\nodejs\node_modules/npm`'s directory, I set it now to have permission for all application packages. I can't mark the answer as correct until I try and install a new package.